# perl - how to read mulitple files in a directory and store data to a unique variable

Tags: arrays, perl

I want to read in mulitple files from a directory and store each value in a unique variable so I can print it out later with a descriptive header. The file names have a common prefix, but are unique.

I know how to open up one file, but is there an efficient way to open up many files? or do i have open unique file handles for each one?  thanks.

Filenames have a common prefix like (abc_*):

```
abc_foo_dir
abc_bar.dat1.20101208
abc_bar.dat2.20101209
```

Example opening up first file:

```
open FILE, "< /home/test/data/abc_foo_dir";
while (<FILE>) {
my $line = $_;
chomp($line);
print "$line\n";
}
close FILE;
```

Comment: Is this homework? Plus, you're not actually doing anything with the contents, just printing it back out again.

Comment: not homework, i'm building this program up. i want to eventually print the data out to a file that will be used for another program. i am basically looking at an easy way to read more than one file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You say "store each value in a unique variable", but this is actually a task for a hash table.

```
my %file_contents;
foreach my $filename (qw(...filenames here... or use a glob to fetch them))
{
    open my $fh, '<', $filename or die "Cannot open $filename: $!";
    local $/;   # enable slurp mode

    # read in the entire contents of the file and store in the hash
    $file_contents{$filename} = <$fh>;

    # this would close automatically when going out of scope,
    # but it's nice to be explicit
    close $fh;
}
```

You can iterate through all the keys later with `keys %file_contents`, but if you aren't familiar with how to work with hashes, I urge you to read [perldoc perldata](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html) and [perldoc perlsyn](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html).

Comment: @jda6one9 To get the keys of a hash, use 'keys'. e.g.   foreach my $key (sort keys %my_hash) { ... }   You can, of course, leave out the 'sort' bit, if the order does not matter, or you can use a more sophisticated way of sorting.

Answer (score 0):

There's the `ARGV / @ARGV` hack. `ARGV` is a special filehandle that will read from all of the files named in the (also special) variable `@ARGV`. Normally `@ARGV` holds the command-line arguments that your Perl program was invoked with, but you are allowed to change it.

```
{
    #local @ARGV = ('abc_foo_dir', 'abc_bar.dat1.20101208', ...);
    local @ARGV = glob("$dir/abc_*");

    while (<ARGV>) {
        print "Read a line from $ARGV: $_";    # $ARGV holds name of current file
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Am not a Perl guru but I will try something simple,

Why dont you temporarily concatenate all files into a single file and then read it.

AFAIK, there is no way to read all file from a single handle.